# Vagrant mysql with MySQLWB

Tags: mysql, ssh, vagrant, puphpet

I have troubl with my mysql connection on my virtual web server based on Vagrant (generate vy puphpet).

Here is my config.yaml file :

```
mysql:
install: '1'
settings:
    version: '5.7'
    root_password: root
    override_options: {  }
users:
    mysqlnu_g4zwm0e6h33a:
        name: dbuser
        password: '123'
databases:
    mysqlnd_nkb9ddpcuuej:
        name: dbname
        sql: ''
grants:
    mysqlng_upoq7qlhcza1:
        user: dbuser
        table: '*.*'
        privileges:
            - ALL
```

On MySQLWorkBench, i have tried to connect with a SSH tunnel with this informations :

- Connection method : over SSH
- SSH Hostname : 127.0.0.1:22
- SSH Username : vagrant
- SSH password : vagrant
- SSH keyfile : file/dot/ssh/id_rsa (no extension)
- Mysql Host : 127.0.0.1
- Mysql Port : 3306 (default)
- Mysql Username : root
- Mysql password : root

I have this error message :

> Failed to connect so MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 thought SSH tunnel at vagrant@127.0.0.1:22 with user root. bad conversion

I don't know why, maybe it's a port error ? If you have a idea , i'm in ! 
But please, don't give me the solution, just a little help, i want to resolve it by myself !

Best regards (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Your SSH hostname should actually be your VM's IP address, which defaults to `192.168.56.101` on puphpet.com

Answer (score 1):

Probleme solved !

First, i type "vagrant ssh-config" (until my VM was running) to retrieve informations : hostname, user, port, rsa_key)

Then, in mysqlWB , the SSh port wasn't 22 but 2222. and of course, using SSH key, i don't need anymore password :)